# Does the impedance profile of flexible PCBs include the adhesive layers?

Tags: altium, impedance-matching, fpc

I'm looking at [this page](https://www.pcbway.com/pcb_prototype/Stack_up_for_FPC.html) on PCBway and trying to get these values into Altium in order to get the right impedance profile.

As I understand, I should use the finished copper thickness to get the right profile.

What I don't know is how thick to make the core. Do I include the width of the adhesive or not? It makes quite a difference to the final Z value.  If I am to include the adhesive, do I have to make any changes to the dielectric constant?

(Yes, I'm already talking to PCBway, but it is getting frustrating to get a straight answer on this. When I get a final answer, I'll put it here.)

[image: PCB way stackup]

[image: Altium stackup with 65um]
[image: Altium stackup with 25um]

**[update]**
I finally got to the bottom of this. Basically yes. You include the adhesive and it doesn't much change the dielectric konstant. I'll accept @65Roadster's answer.

I'll just add here: If you want impedance matching at any thickness greater than 0.1mm. You might find a significant price increase (3-4x on orders of 700 units) due to the difficulties to accurately lay down the finishing copper in a consistent way. Further more, they might not even do it at all. This is something consider if you want to run sizeable currents though adjacent power connections and are considering thicker copper layers.

Comment: What Impedance value ? What standard PCB thickness are you aiming for ? For most 1.6mm standard PCBs you should be able to get straight answer from the PCB manufacturer what laminates they intend to use and their thicknesses etc. Then you can work out the "right profile" (whatever this may be)...

Comment: You should in this case specify 65µm in Altium. The total distance between the copper layers is what matters.
Regarding changing the dielectric constant, I wouldn't bother. As long as the trace widths/spacings you are using are in the right ballpark, the PCB manufacturer will then fine tune the widhts and dielectric thickness to get the right impedance according to your specifications during manufacturing.

Comment: Sorry @citizen. I missed the part stating that its a flexible PCB. Not an FR4 core. I edited the question now so that it makes more sense

Comment: What Klas-Kenny said.  We give the PWB fab house nominal trace widths, spacings, etc (based on the board stackup & materials), then allow them to adjust (usually) trace widths and to achieve the target nominal impedance value for the traces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do the same as others have said, I design with nominal dimensions that are close, then the flex house adjusts and they guarantee impedance (e.g. +/-10%).

I do take into account the adhesive and coverlay for my nominal dimensions. There is an appreciable impact on the top side fields of micro strip structures. It can be modeled as an effective dielectric constant but the way you’re doing it is better, just put all the layers into Altium for nominals but ask the flex house for actual microstrip dimensions and use those in the end.

Comment: I talk to the board house when dealing with critical impedances. I'll sometimes run a test trace in the project so I can measure the impedance when I get the board back to verify the impedance.

Comment: Thanks!. I accept your answer. Hadn't really thought about the coverlay. How does one account for that?

Comment: I’d get the dimensions and materials from the PCB house and put those into the impedance calculator. I use HFSS for this kind of work. But at the end of the day I use whatever the board house suggests.